# how to save drawing into mysql?

Tags: mysql-workbench, vb.net-2010

I have a method that user can draw on the picturebox anything they want, but the problem is I can't save the drawing into MySQL, when I try to save the picture box the image on it can only be saved but the drawing I apply on the PictureBox has not been saved.

**This is my save button code:**

```vb
Private Sub btnsave_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnsave.Click
    Dim mstream As New System.IO.MemoryStream()
    pbtest.Image.Save(mstream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
    Dim arrImage() As Byte = mstream.GetBuffer()
    MysqlConn = New MySqlConnection
    MysqlConn.ConnectionString =
        "server=localhost;userid=root;password=rico;database=god;"
    Try
        MysqlConn.Open()
        COMMAND.CommandText = "insert into god.precord (picture) values (@picture)"
        COMMAND.Connection = MysqlConn
        COMMAND.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        COMMAND.Parameters.AddWithValue("@picture", arrImage)
        COMMAND.ExecuteNonQuery()
        MessageBox.Show("Data Saved")
        MysqlConn.Close()

    Catch ex As MySqlException
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    Finally
        MysqlConn.Dispose()
    End Try
```

Please help me I'm stuck on it.

Answer (score 0):

If you can save the image drawn on the picturebox onto local disk, then you can do this:
On your SQL table, define the datatype of the picture column as varbinary (max). Example:

```
Create table tblA (Picture varbinary (max));
Create proc uspInsertPictureA @Picture varbinary (max) as insert into tblA (Picture) values (@Picture);
```

Then, in your VB.Net application, do this:

```
Command.Parameters.Add("@Picture", SqlDbType.VarBinary).Value = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(PictureBox1.ImageLocation) --> Change PictureBox1 to your PictureBox name
Command.ExecuteNonQuery
```

That will save your picturebox image to your SQL database. Then, to retrieve the picture from your SQL Server database into your VB.Net application, do this:

```
Command.CommandText = "Select Picture from tblA"
Dim BLOB = DirectCast(Command.ExecuteScalar, Byte())
Dim Picture = New System.IO.MemoryStream
Picture.write(BLOB, 0, BLOB.Length)
PictureBox.Image = New Bitmap(Picture)
```

I hope this helps. However, if I may suggest, you had better save the image drawn on the picturebox onto local disk and then save the file location instead of the picture itself onto the SQL Server database. Saving picture/image onto SQL Server database increases resource consumption and may lead to performance issues, especially if your application runs on a network or has a large database.